# Let $\tau$ and $\tau'$ be two topologies in a topological space $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ and $\tau'$ be two topologies in a topological space $X$. For all $U \in \tau$ there exists $U' \in \tau'$ such that $U' \subset U$. Can we compare $\tau$ and $\tau'$?

Comment: You'd want $U' \neq \emptyset$ I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarly. Take $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $\tau=\{\varnothing, \{a,b\},X\}$ and $\tau'=\{\varnothing, \{a\},X\}$. Those are obviously topologies and they satisfy your condition. However, we have neither $\tau \subset \tau'$ nor $\tau'\subset \tau$.

Note: If you modify your condition by asking that for all $x\in X$ and for all $x\in U \in \tau$ there exists $x\in U'\in \tau'$ such that $U'\subset U$, it is a standard result that then $\tau \subset \tau'$. This stronger condition is not satified in my counterexample at the point $b$.